# VB console app - Why does array.Min() method return a value of 0 in the sorted array when 0 was not entered

Tags: arrays, vb.net, methods, console

its a very simple program to show GCSE students how to use array functions such as min(), max() etc but the results are incorrect when the data is entered via a For Loop - they work when the data is part of the array coding.

```
Dim testscores(10) As Integer
    'Dim testscores = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}  'min function works on this but not when values are entered using the FOR loop
    Dim studentname As String
    For x = 0 To 9
        Console.WriteLine("this is the x value " & x)
        Console.WriteLine("please enter a test score")
        testscores(x) = Console.ReadLine()
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    For y = 0 To 9
        Console.WriteLine("element y is " & y & "  " & " the value stored is " & testscores(y))
    Next
    Array.Sort(testscores)
    Console.WriteLine()
    For y = 0 To 9
        Console.WriteLine("after sorting - element y is " & y & "  " & " the value stored is " & testscores(y))
    Next`
```

Output looks like this:
[output when entering sequence of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcWsF.png)

Comment: How many elements are you declaring here: `Dim testscores(10) As Integer`? -- Set `Option Strict ON`

Comment: Dim testscores(10) As Integer creates an array with 11 elements, then your only iterating the 1st 10 elements when entering values and printing output. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/.    Alternative set the upper bounds of your for loops to testscores.Length - 1

Comment: Integer is a Value type. Value types have default values. The default value of an Integer is Zero. The 11th element of your array is filled in with the default value of Integer.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out, this line:

```
Dim testscores(10) As Integer
```

Causes this 11-long array to be created:

```
{0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0}
```

You then use a loop to give 10 of the items a value. let's suppose your users entered 5 every time:

```
{5,5,5, 5,5,5, 5,5,5, 5,0}
```

The last element is never set and keeps its default value of 0 which `Min()` is happy to find for you..

If you want to declare arrays using the **size** rather than the **last index**, may I suggest C#? :)